# wso2 api manager parameters in context of URL

Tags: url, parameters, wso2, wso2-api-manager, publisher

wso2 api manager has the following parts in the publisher URL:

```
http//hostname:8280/<context>/<version>/<resource>
```

I know that `<resource>` can be defined with parameters within curly brackets, like `{parameter}` and they can be used duiring mediation using `uri.var.parameter`.

I was trying to use the parameter in curly brackets in `<context>` part of the publisher URL, but unfortunately this does not work.

Is there any way how to use parameters in `<context>` and work with them during mediation flow?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, the context determines which API is invoked and that value is fixed when you create the API?

Answer (score 0):

`{version}` is the only parameter you can use inside the context.